# How to get Baseline X dates in Project server 2016 from Database?

Tags: sharepoint, project-server, ms-project-server-2013, ms-project-server-2016

How can I get Baseline´s columns from Project Server?

[image]

It is not possible to get them using CSOM. Also, I couldn´t find them in database script.

[image]

Is it the correct database? Is it pjpub, pjver or pjdraft? What is the correct table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find project and task baselines data in database views:
`[pjrep].[MSP_EpmProject_UserView]`
`[pjrep].[MSP_EpmTask_UserView]`
Columns names start with TaskBaselineXX...